# how to clear canvas in android

Tags: android, pdf, canvas, annotations

After experimenting with composite operations and **annotation pdf** on the canvas I'm now trying to remove annotation when a new page call.

How do I do this?

**I need to clear the canvas for new annotations;**

this can go on for a while so I don't think annotation  a new rectangle every time will be the most efficient option even as the PDF render every time when any page call...

so how do i clear the annotation to show the clear new page.........

I had also used PorterDuff.Mode.clear this also did not work in my case.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just call

```
 Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)
```

Comment: not working i had tried this already...
i am using two different views one for PDF rendering & other is for annotation on PDF. both are generating dynamically..
if i use black color & whole screen will be black

Comment: So "clearing the canvas" would mean u want it completely black/white. But anyway... What about saving the screen in a bitmap and then draw it again over the whole screen? Do u have more infos?

Comment: in storing the bitmap its can be memoryOverflow error thats why i am generating the whole PDf every time to it wont give this error....

Comment: In his case it did work, also for mine. it depends wether your canvas has a default black bg or not.